# Microsoft.Graph, c# sdk, trying to get list of driveitems from onedrive root folder: Error "DriveRequestBuilder does not contain a definition for Root

Tags: onedrive, microsoft-graph-sdks

.NET MAUI App,

I am trying to get a list of Children from Root folder on Drive... I get this error in edition/compile time, when I use a snippet of code from MS Learn:

'DriveRequestBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'Root' and no accessible extension method 'Root' accepting a first argument of type 'DriveRequestBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I just cloned a sample project developed by microsoft staff and inserted a snippet of code from MS Learn.

Pls, get the entire project with the error here:

https://github.com/leoderja/DriveRequestBuilder_RootNotDefined.git

The error is in:

> MauiAppBasic.csproj project ->
> MSALClient folder ->
> MSGraphHelper.cs file ->
> TestRootChildrenAsync method

Using Microsoft.Graph version 5.0.0-rc.1

EDITION: Here a minimal example:

```
using Microsoft.Graph;
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(new HttpClient());
var children = await graphClient.Me.Drive.Root.Children.Request().GetAsync();
```

The problem was Microsoft.Graph v5.00 rc1. When I set v4.50 the errors disappeared. I hope that Microsoft staff update the documentation with the changes when final release of v5 is available.

[image: Img 1]

[image: Img 2]

Comment: Can you please provide a [mre]? See [ask] for further guidance on asking questions. Posting a link to an entire project does not count as providing a [mre].

Comment: Hi @starball, thank you for your help and time. When I followed your indications could get the answer to my question... The problem is Microsoft.Graph v5.00rc1, when I downgraded to v4.50 the errors disappeared. I updated the question to include a snippet of code with a minimal example.

Comment: If you know enough to explain the reason why v5.00rc1 doesn't work and v4.50 does, you can write and answer post (see [answer]).

Comment: Dear @starball, I think it's due to functionality or object model changes between versions, but I'm not sure... v4.5 is enough for me for now... that's why I just downgraded the package.. I appreciate your help to know the guidelines to behave properly in stackoverflow, I will take it into account in my future interventions on this site

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since version 5 the `Root` is accessible through `Drives[userDriveId]` but not through `Me.Drive`

```
var children = await client.Drives[userDriveId].Root.Children.GetAsync();
```

If you don't know the user's drive id you need to call `Me.Drive`.

```
var driveItem = await client.Me.Drive.GetAsync();
var children = await client.Drives[driveItem.Id].Root.Children.GetAsync();
```

Comment: Thank you, @user2250152. I wonder where these documented changes can be found?

Comment: Try this doc on GitHub: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/feature/5.0/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md#drive-item-paths

Comment: What if you used Search() on this Root() object? It also no longer has that definition. I am seeing breaking changes like this everywhere but no documentaiton showing small changes like this.

Comment: Good answer, but unfortunately already out of date as children will be null.  See Rick Kozak's correct answer above

Comment: @publicwireless Agree that Rick's answer is much better. When I added this answer, SDK v5 was new and everyone was confused how to do basic things

Answer (score 8):

Hope this saves someone the couple of hours I spent looking. The current correct answer is:

```
var children = await client.Drives[driveItem.Id].Items["root"].Children.GetAsync();
```

see https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/1737

Comment: This was exactly what i was looking for, i had spent half a day and given up. Reading all the official documentation at the time aswell as numerous examples and tutorials on how to just simply get the children/items/files inside drive and folder. I would always run into .Children/.Root/.Request not existing in certain paths. From reading this post i can see that this just seems to be undocumented changes, which i dont understand why a large corporation's own documentation would not reflect the latest version.

Comment: Yeah after a lot of confusion this particular syntax worked for me, as of Sept 2023.  Hopefully it doesn't change in a couple months YET AGAIN!

Comment: Thank you! I spent several hours searching and trying unsuccessfully, this is the correct solution!